# Checkbox Inside a Data Grid not changed the checked event on Button click event for the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a data grid with four columns which includes 3 text column and a checkbox. Clicking on checkbox of different rows then click on delete button needs to remove the checked rows from data grid.

But the checked event not firing up for the first time when i clicked on Delete button but the next time it fires and the checked value of the checkbox is true.

It would be grateful if i have a solution for this.
thanks in advance.

Note : I have used Data Grid not Gridview and i don't have row property.

I have added a checkbox as Item template inside a Data Grid.

```
<asp:CheckBox OnCheckedChanged="id_CheckedChanged" runat="server"  Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DeleteCheckboxVisible")  %>' ></asp:CheckBox>
```

addded OnCheckedChanged event in code behind.

```
 protected void id_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox lnkView = (sender as CheckBox);

            if (lnkView.Checked)
            {
                Response.Write("you checked the checkbox");
            }
            else if (!lnkView.Checked)
            {
                Response.Write("checkbox is not checked");
            }
        }
```

In the button Click Event

``````````````
 protected void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {



                foreach (DataGridItem row in DataGridEmployeeLifeEvents.Items)
                {
                    if (row.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
                    {
                        CheckBox chkVjezba = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxDelete");

                        if (chkVjezba.Checked)
                        {
                            //something
                        }
                    }

                }
}

`````````````
``````````````

Comment: So you are saying `id_CheckedChanged` is not called when you click the checkbox?

Comment: yes Tim it is not called